# How to target a specific div class within a specific parent div class, python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have two divs that look like this:

```
<div id="RightColumn">
   <div class="profile-info">   
       <div class= "info">
       </div>
       <div class="title">
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How do I target the internal div labelled "title"? It appears multiple times on the page but the one that I need to target is within "RightColumn".

Here is the code I tried:

```
mainDIV = driver.find_element_by_id("RightColumn")
targetDIV = mainDIV.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="title"]').text
```

Unfortunately the above code still pulls all title divs on the page vs the one I need within the mainDiv.

Comment: Hi. There are 2 answers. Hopefully one or both are helpful to you!

Answer (score 0):

This will select the first title div under this element:

```
mainDIV.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="title"]
```

However, this will select the first title on the page:

```
mainDIV.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="title"]
```

**Try:**

```
targetDIV = mainDIV.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="title"]').text
```

Note as of Selenium 4.0.0, the *find_element_by_** functions are deprecated and should be replaced with *find_element()*.

```
targetDIV = mainDIV.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@class="title"]').text
```

**Reference:**

[WebDriver API - find_element_by_xpath](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=find_element#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_element_by_xpath)

Answer (score 0):

```
//div[@id='RightColumn']//child::div[@class='title']
```

this should get the job done.

first use id `RightColumn` to taget div and then title class div is a child.